# Указание href тэгу button

Tags: php, html

Я раньше указывал авторизацию с тэгом  и тд а вот стала задача сделать это с тегом баттон но как с тегом  не проканало( подскажите как это реализовать ниже код:

```
<body>
  <button id='button' onclick='window.location.href='https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=".$appid."&display=page&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&scope=".$scope."&response_type=code&v=5.80''>АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ</button>
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='500' height='500'></canvas>
    <script  src='js/index.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: какая-то каша с одинарными и двойными кавычками

Comment: @Igor это я заменил "" на '' ибо это все у меня в echo) и пхп ругается на стандартные скобки)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте нормальный обработчик клика по кнопке:

```
<body>
  <button id='button' onclick='buttonClick()'>АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ</button>
  <canvas id='myCanvas' width='500' height='500'></canvas>
  <script src='js/index.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      function buttonClick(){
           window.location.href='https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=".$appid."&display=page&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&scope=".$scope."&response_type=code&v=5.80';
      }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kакая-то каша с одинарными и двойными кавычками.

Значение атрибута `onclick` в приведенном коде `window.location.href=`.